# Sort list while in a loop using groupby

Tags: list, linq

I have a loop with linq like this:

```
foreach (var group in part.Profiles.Skip(ixstart).
             GroupBy(b => new { b.Number, b.X }).
             OrderBy(g => g.Key.Number).ThenBy(g => g.Key.X))
{
     // .... code
}
```

Is it safe to somewhere in the ... code sort the list
`part.Profiles.Sort()`?
I do not get exceptions.

Comment: It depends on what you expect. The foreach-loop will not change it's order just because you have changed the order of the underlying collection. But you dont get any exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it *turns out* to be safe because `GroupBy` doesn't stream results - it consumes *all* of the input before it returns any values. (It's *lazy* in that it doesn't do any work until you ask it for its first element, but then it consumes all of the input.)

However, I would definitely *not* rely on that. It's going to ring alarm bells for many readers, and a seemingly-innocent change could mess everything up. I'd also say it's a confusing thing to do at all, sorting a collection within a loop that's iterating over that collection. Options:

- Sort beforehand
- Sort afterwards
- Materialize the collection you're iterating over so it's independent of the original collection (e.g. by calling `ToList()` and using the result)

Comment: Ok. It works but it is an alarm bell. That's the reason I am struggling because some items just have to shift. I will then collect the shifted items in a seperate property and insert them "manually" at the correct `Key`.

Comment: @Gerard: To be honest without more context of what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to give more advice beyond "Don't do it in the loop." :(

Comment: I understand, it is a little bit complicated. Some items must be processed later on but it can only be detected while looping.
Still for now it helped me to trust  the `GroupBy`.